# C++ adding numbers from input file

Tags: c++

I am trying to open files with list of int numbers. I just want to output the total number of numbers in the file, and add together all the numbers from the file.

This is the part that I am having problems with:

```
void workFunc(ifstream& myInput, string fileName, int& count, int& sum)

{
//int count = 0;
//int sum = 0;
int num;
myInput >> num;

while (myInput.good())
{
    myInput >> num;
    count++;
    sum += num;
}

}
```

It is giving me the right count, but not adding the numbers together properly every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't count the first thing you read, but you count the last thing twice. So you get the count right by accident, but of course get the sum wrong unless the first and last values happen to be the same.

You read something into `num` and then enter the loop. The first thing your loop does is read into `num` again, discarding the previous value. So the first value doesn't get counted. You then increment `count` and add it to `sum` whether or not the read succeeded, which counts the last value twice.

You want this:

```
myInput >> num;

while (myInput.good())
{
    // First count the value that we just read
    count++;
    sum += num;

    // Then read the next value
    myInput >> num;
}
```

Comment: All I needed, was spending too much time on something I knew would be simple. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify that to:

```
int num;
while (myInput >> num)
{
    count++;
    sum += num;
}
```